# AngularJS routing not working after adding second state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the ui.router. First when I just set the home state everything was working fine. But after adding the articles state my routing wouldn't work. I have following angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('ibrahimsBlog', ['ui.router'])

app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'PrimaryController'
    });

    .state('articles', {
      url: '/articles/{id}',
      templateUrl: '/articles.html',
      controller: 'ArticlesController'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])

app.factory('articlesFactory', [function(){
  var art = { articles: [] };
  return art;
}])

app.controller('ArticlesController', [
'$scope',
'$stateParams',
'articlesFactory',
function($scope, $stateParams, articlesFactory){
  $scope.article = articlesFactory.articles[$stateParams.id];
}]);

app.controller('PrimaryController', [
// Two Way Data Binding ist nur möglich mit scope Variablen.
'$scope',
'articlesFactory',
function($scope, articlesFactory) {

  $scope.articles = articlesFactory.articles;

  $scope.articles = [
    { title : 'foo', content : "foo", likes : 5, date : '12/15/2014' },
    { title : 'bar', content : "bar", likes : 2, date : '12/14/2014' },
    { title : 'baz', content : "baz", likes : 4, date : '12/23/2014' }
  ];

  $scope.addArticle = function() {

    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }

    $scope.articles.push(
      {
        title: $scope.title,
        content: $scope.content,
        likes: 0,
        date: '12/15/2014',
        comments: [
          { author: 'foo', comment: 'bar', upvotes: 0 }
        ]
      }
    );
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.content = '';
  }

  $scope.likeArticle = function(article) {
    article.likes += 1;
  }
}]);
```

And here is my html file:

```
<html>

 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Ibrahims Blog</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style> .glyphicon-heart { cursor:pointer } </style>
 </head>

 <body ng-app="ibrahimsBlog">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

     <ui-view></ui-view>

     <form ng-submit="addArticle()" style="margin-top:30px;">
      <h3>Create a new article!</h3>

       <div class=form-group">
        <input type="text"
         placeholder="title"
         ng-model="title">
        </input>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"
         placeholder="content"
         ng-model="content">
        </input>
       </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Hinzufügen</button>
     </form>

     <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
      <div class="page-header">
       <h1>Ibrahims Blog</h1>
      </div>
      <span>
      <a href="#/articles/{{ index }}">Go</a>
      </span>
     </script>

     <script type=text/ng-template" id="/articles.html">
      <div class="page-header">
       <h3> {{ article.title }} </h3>
      </div>

      <div ng-repeat="article in articles">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"
       ng-click="likeArticle(article)"></span>
       {{ article.title }} - "{{ article.content }}" - Likes: {{ article.likes }}, Date: {{ article.date }}
      </div>
    </script>

   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately everything I receive is following part of the html

```
<form ng-submit="addArticle()" style="margin-top:30px;">
 <h3>Create a new article!</h3>

 <div class=form-group">
  <input type="text"
  placeholder="title"
  ng-model="title">
  </input>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text"
  placeholder="content"
  ng-model="content">
  </input>
 </div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Hinzufügen</button>
 </form>
```

**Edit**
Unfortunately there is still a part which is not working.. When I use the *Go* button, I see the change of the URL, but it then instant redirects me to the home template. On the server I get a 404 Error. Do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have a semi-colon in the wrong place when defining the $stateProvider.  You aren't chaining the .state calls properly because the first semi-colon terminates the statement:

```
$stateProvider

.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: '/home.html',
  controller: 'PrimaryController'
});  // <-------------------------Remove this semi-colon!

.state('articles', {
  url: '/articles/{id}',
  templateUrl: '/articles.html',
  controller: 'ArticlesController'
});
```

Comment: jeeeez that was everything .. :D there should be a stack site like code  review: searching for dumb fails

Comment: @IbrahimApachi that would have produced a javascript error in the console with a link to the file and line number. Try checking the console for errors when something doesn't work.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini This might be a dumb question since I am a bit new to the whole mean stack, but I am using node JS as server and I didn't get any errors there. Where should I look at ? Do I have to enable troubleshooting ?

Comment: This would be in the dev console in Chrome or Firefox browser.  It's a client side error so it's shows up in the browser.

Comment: @chubbsondubs Hey chubbs, when I click on the *Go* button I get directed to the right URL but instantly redirected to my *home* page. The Server gives me a 404. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: So I imagine you have Angular configured for html5 routing vs hash bang mode.  In html5 routing the URLs route off the path portion of the URL.  In hash bang mode they route off the fragment portion of the URL.  In html5 mode your server has to cooperate with being sent URLs that aren't actually mapped to services so it will not 404 an unknown URL.  When your server gets an unknown URL it has to send back the HTML that powers your angular app as if it existed.  In hashbang mode it doesn't round trip the server and your server can behave as normal.

Comment: @chubbsondubs I feel stupid right now, because I probably missed the quintessence of your text, but I didn't get further with your information :/

Comment: I maybe off about hashbang mode vs html5 after I read your code.  What URL does the go button route to? What is the URL in the browser when it gets a 404? Are they the same or different?

Comment: Why did you remove my edit ? I can't accept your answer and give you the bounty with out my addition.. The quotation marks were another failure too

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see what you are seeing with respect to a missing semicolon so I can't edit my question :-D

Comment: In my template in this line `<script type=text/ng-template" id="/articles.html">` the quotation marks were missing! That was the reason for the 404. It should be like this: `<script type="text/ng-template" id="/articles.html">`

Answer (score 0):

Like chubbsondubs stated, I had to remove a semicolon. But since that was just a cause for one problem here is the other fault I found later on. In my template in this line

```
<script type=text/ng-template" id="/articles.html">
```

The quotation marks were missing! That was the reason for the 404. It should be like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/articles.html">
```